# New: Correct Spyder Syntax

Tags: python, syntax, spyder

I'm new to Python. Trying to implement some code in Spyder.

"Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]"

I'm trying to implement some code from a video on Neural Nets.

```python
def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if(deriv=true):
        return(x*(1-x))
```

The code is returning

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

My question is 2 part:

1. What is the correct syntax?
2. Where can I go to familiarize myself with the standard format? It looks like there are multiple syntaxes that work depending on the version/type. Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places.

Comment: I think your question is not correct because i think this is a python syntax error not a spyder syntax error.

Comment: Like Pils19 said, syntax errors (like "grammar errors") are errors in the language. It doesn't matter what word processor/editor you use (like Spyder). Also, it would really hope if you could post the code correctly formatted. See if you can figure out Stackoverflow's code formatting.

Comment: Sorry for the issue with the code formatting. I can see why that would be frustrating. Any recommendation on where I can go to familiarize myself with the Python 3.6.3 syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First learn to format the code when you are asking a question because it's incmorehensive 
the keyword "True" goest with the first letter in uppercase and second you have to go "==" instead of a single "="

```
def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if (deriv==True):
        return (x * (1 - x))

print(nonlin(29, deriv=False))
print(nonlin(29, deriv=True))
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Any suggestion on where I can become more familiar with the appropriate syntax? Early days here and I want to get off of relying on the community to debug basic errors.

Comment: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/ here man this one is the best out there

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ If you want to learn some more advanced syntax.